# Different Reducers by Key in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, distributed

I have a large-scale data processing problem that I'm trying to solve with Apache Spark in Java.   My input is a large set of relatively small custom Java objects.

My map step performs some minor alterations to each object.  Once that's done, it identifies one or more equivalence classes to which the object belongs.  Combined, there may be many billions of equivalence class/object pairs.

My problem is that I need to perform different operations on the elements of each equivalence class.  This project needs to support a plug-in architecture, so I don't know what the equivalence classes are, or the different operations that will need to happen on each class.

My intuition is to use something like the following:

```
//Get the input set.
JavaRDD<MyType> input = ... //Not important

//Transform the input into (Equivalence Class, MyType) pairs, 
//using strings to store the equivalence class.
JavaPairRDD<String, MyType> classedInput = input.flatMapToPair(

    new PairFlatMapFunction<MyType, String, MyType>() {

        Iterator<Tuple2<String, MyType>> call(MyType arg) {

            List<Tuple2<String, MyType>> out = new ArrayList<>();

            //Compute equivalence classes for arg.
            for(String eqClz: getEquivalenceClasses(arg)) {
                out.add(new Tuple2<String, MyType>(equClz, arg));
            }

            return out.iterator();
        }
});

//Collapse the results for each equivalence class.
JavaPairRDD<String, MyType> output = classedInput.reduceByKey(

    new Function2<MyType, MyType, MyType>() {

        MyType call(MyType a, MyType b) {
            String eqClz = ??? //<= Problem
            List<MyModule> modules = MyFramework.getModulesForEqClz(eqClz);
            for(MyModule m: modules) {
               a = m.merge(a, b);
            }
            return a;
        }
    }

);
```

I would like to be able to pass the equivalence class into the function for reduceByKey, in order to use it to determine which modules need to be invoked.  The problem is that none of Spark's keyed combiner functions I can find pass the key into their callbacks.

Due to the size of classedInput, I would like to avoid saving the key with the MyType object, or adding too many extra distributed operations after the map.

Is there a more Spark-like way to accomplish what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is the inverse of the ["secondary sort"](https://www.quora.com/What-is-secondary-sort-in-Hadoop-and-how-does-it-work) issue. And it can be solved by the inverse solution, I think (below in 2.).

1. One way is to use the `reduce` function (or its more complete version, `aggregate`), which just requires an associative operation for you to summarise the results of your data, irrespective of the key. But expressing the details of your grouping of items in the same equivalence class may get a bit complex.
2. The simpler way to keep a reference on the equivalence class against which the items were matched is to simply repeat the equivalence class in the value:

`Tuple2<String, MyType> outValue = new Tuple2<String, MyType>(eqClz, arg);
out.add(new Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, MyType>>(equClz, outValue));`

If, as you mentioned in a comment, you are worried about the size of the shuffle when you are transferring your data, maybe what you want to limit is the size of the representation used as a keying construct. What I mean by that is that repeating the key in the value as suggested above leads to two copies of the equClz variable. But if is a dozen bytes, the one whose size you want to reduce is the copy in the key position. To do that, you may want to choose a non-cryptographic hash of the right length.

You mentioned that a dozen more bytes per record would lead to gigabytes more data, which should mean you have at most few hundred million records, and thus at the very most a few hundred million "equClz" values. That's easily covered by a 32 bits non-cryptographic hash (you'll easily find implementations of these, Murmur3, XXHash). Since 32 bits is 4 bytes, it should reduce your transfer overhead by at least an order of magnitude.

Comment: To start, great answers.  For my specific use case, I worry about the memory and network use of these solutions.

For 1., my understanding of Spark's .reduce() is that it returns a single result to the caller.  Given the number of separate artifacts, I'd like to avoid collecting them all in one place at one time.

For 2. I'd worry about associating extra data with each value.  My intuition is that that a couple dozen more bytes per record would equate to sending gigabytes or more of additional data across the wire.  Is this reasonable, or am I off base?